# UITableView delete rows without scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am building a feed of unseen images `image.seen = 0`

I have a `NSFetchedResultsController` bundled with a `UITableViewController`.

I am marking `image.seen = 1` at `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath`.

when my users scrolls to row2 containing image2, image1 will be updated and row1 will be deleted.

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    break;
```

however, when you delete row1, the `UITableView` will remember that you are currently at scroll position 1 from the top and maintain that scrolling position for you when the deletion occurs.

hence, you will get scrolled to row3. row2 now goes out of view and gets deleted. when deletion is complete, table will scroll you to row4....

How can I get around this?

Comment: UITableView isn't actually scrolling when you delete a row.

Comment: @troop231 yes it does. Check this sample project I built. http://bit.ly/10TMBba

Comment: My bad, I didn't actually think that was considered scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

we can delete rows in canEditRowAtIndexPath  tableview delegate if we want to delete rows externally,if we load from array remove recored from particular index in array based on row number of tableView and reload the data.